# How do I customise the Bootstrap 5 Mixins

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I am looking to change the .btn-primary color to $white and add a box-shadow. I know there is a very simple way to do this in plain CSS, but I am just learning to customise the Bootstrap SCSS.

I have a separate .scss file which have the below:

```
@import "../../assets/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

@mixin button-variant($color:$white) {
   color: $white;
   box-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

How do I customise/edit/add to existing mixins?

Answer (score 0):

> "How do I customise/edit/add to existing mixins?"

The simplest way is to @include the mixin. Notice that the button-variant mixin has 2 required params for background and border color...

```
@import "bootstrap";

.btn-primary {
    @include button-variant($white,$white)
    box-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/1yMCHkOaOR)

Use the other @mixin parameters as desired...

```
@mixin button-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $color: color-contrast($background),
  $hover-background: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($background, 15%), tint-color($background, 15%)),
  $hover-border: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($border, 20%), tint-color($border, 10%)),
  $hover-color: color-contrast($hover-background),
  $active-background: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($background, 20%), tint-color($background, 20%)),
  $active-border: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($border, 25%), tint-color($border, 10%)),
  $active-color: color-contrast($active-background),
  $disabled-background: $background,
  $disabled-border: $border,
  $disabled-color: color-contrast($disabled-background)
)...
```

Comment: The code above changes the background colour to white. I am looking to change the color (font) to white.

Comment: The primary button already has a white font color. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

The mixin parameterized `button-variant`, can be used to create customized coloured buttons.The mixin declaration is as:

```
@mixin button-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $hover-background,
  $hover-border,
  $active-background,
  $active-border
);
```

`$background` and `$border` parameters must be provided, and rest are optional parameters. It automatically generates button text color in contrast to the provided background color.

```
@import node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixin;

$feature-bg: #ffd803;

.btn-feature {
  @include button-variant($feature-bg, darken($feature-bg, 3%));

  // optitional
  // color: #fff; #uncomment and add your color
}
```

In html
`<button class="btn btn-feature">Feature</button>`

Read more: https://themightyprogrammer.dev/snippet/custom-bootstrap-button